# How to create an int pointer on the stack?

Tags: c++

```
void func(int* param){};
func(&123); //error: '&' on constant
funct(&int(123)) //error
```

Comment: `int(123)` still doesn't allocate memory you can take the address of. It's a literal, typecasted to `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how pointers work.

You must first allocate memory for your 123, like this:

```
int x = 123;
func(&x);
```

Comment: He asked how to create pointer on stack, not on heap. Second example also lacks `free(x);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't take the address of a temporary. Address-of operator (`&`) requires an `lvalue` as an argument.

```
void func(int* param){};
int main(){
  int k = 123;
  func(&k); //fine now
}
```

Comment: `123` is not a temporary, it's a literal.

Comment: `int(123)` is a temporary, 123 isn't

Answer (score 2):

Declare an int variable, and then point to it:

```
int main() {
  int x = 123;
  func(&x);
}
```

If you want to declare a *pointer* on the stack, then declare an int-pointer variable:

```
int* p = &x;
func(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `&` must and should only be applied to actual variables, not operands.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to take the address of an rvalue. Make it an lvalue:

```
n = 123;
func(&n);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void func(int* param)
{
    std::cout << * param << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = 123;
    func(&a);

    return 0;
}
```